# Codecs implemented in Java

Tags: google-tv

I had heard that Google TV V3 supports the ability to add custom codecs implemented in Java, however their appears to be no published public API around this.   Are there any public examples.  The reason I'm asking is that I'm working on a media player and have some requests to allow playback of FLAC files and have found a java library that will decode these files appropriately.

If not any time frame for making such information available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be available within 3 weeks. That would be for the latest OTA to ARM based devices.

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming the apis will be documented on the Samples page of the developers site? https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples